# Can not open Logrocket Dashboard when AdGuard DNS used

Tags: dns, linkedin-api

I setup my WIFI network router with AdGuard DNS to filter out Ads. Works great I even can open Linked in from Russia without VPN. But now I can not access app.logrocket.com

How can I access the app.logrocket.com?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the AdGuard DNS itself. The "Default" and "Family" DNS consider the logrocket as Ads source. To fix that you should use "Non-filtering" DNS servers

This is answer from "Default" AdGuard DNS

```
nslookup logrocket.com 94.140.14.14
Server:     94.140.14.14
Address:    94.140.14.14#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   logrocket.com
Address: 0.0.0.0
```

This is answer from "Non-filtering" AdGuard DNS

```
nslookup logrocket.com 94.140.14.141
Server:     94.140.14.141
Address:    94.140.14.141#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   logrocket.com
Address: 104.26.9.185
Name:   logrocket.com
Address: 104.26.8.185
Name:   logrocket.com
Address: 172.67.75.120
```